# Check checkboxes by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using this code to get a comma separated list of all checkboxes checked.

```
$(".hidFeedsIds").val($.map($(':checkbox[name=channel\[\]]:checked'), function (n, i) {
    return n.value;
}).join(','));
```

Now I need to do the opposite, I have the list but need to check all the checkboxes that the values are on it.

Can anyone tell me how could this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from the fact that your code isn't syntactically valid...

```
$('input:checkbox').filter(function() {
    return valuesArray.indexOf(this.value) > -1
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this, can you explain me whats wrong with my code? its working for me.

Comment: You forgot a `function () {`. Also, not sure why you're `.join()`ing the array to a string.

Comment: Lol i posted the wrong code, just had that on the clipboard and didnt noticed, i tried this and its working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, to complement @Matt's answer.

```
$.each(valuesArray, function (i, v) {

    // or use .prop() if you like, depending on jQuery version
    $("input:checkbox[value='" + v + "']").attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.prop()` be used instead of attr?

Comment: Depends - I like to mention both as some poor people (like myself) still have older jQueries in production.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/imijis/3/edit)**</kbd>

If your elements values share the same ID like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" value="a" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" value="b" />
```

than you can do:

```
$('#'+ valuesArray.join(', #') ).prop('checked', true);
```

---

And btw you are missing `function` in your original script. Should be:

```
var valuesArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join();
```